# DataFrame constructor not properly called! matplotlib.pyplot error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

Trying to make a scatter plot of IMDB ratings of episodes correlated with seasons of Seinfeld

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season_list'[1:], 'imdbRating_list'[1:]})
df.columns = ['Season', 'imdbRating']

df.plot.scatter(x = 'Season', y='imdbRating')
```

I keep getting this error:

`DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a DataFrame from a *set* of two strings, `{'eason_list', 'mdbRating_list'}`. This is because `"Text"[1:]` selects all but the first character of the string, `"Text"[1:] == "ext"`.

However a DataFrame cannot be created from such set. Instead you probably want to use a *dictionary*. A dictionary is created from key, value pairs, `{key1 : value1, key2 : value2}`.

In this case I could imagine you have two lists, `a` and `b`, such that

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season' : a[1:], 'imdbRating' : b[1:]})
```

which would result in the dataframe

```
   Season  imdbRating
0       2           5
1       3           6
```